# SQL - How to check if a given column is a primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I'm currently writing a small sql function to scan through a table and convert the table's columns to an ASP.NET model. It's working quite well so far, but I need to check if the current column is a primary key with a CASE WHEN to be able to give output.

This is what I have currently, but this isn't working.

```
SELECT @result = @result + CHAR(13)
    + '//---' + ColumnName + '---' + CHAR(13)
    + ' [Display(Name = "' + dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case(ColumnName) + '")] ' + CHAR(13)
    + CASE SYS.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
        WHEN 'PRIMARY KEY' THEN 'Testing things and stuff' END
    + CASE bRequired WHEN 'NO' 
    THEN 
    CASE WHEN Len(MaxLen) > 0 THEN ' [Required, StringLength(' + MaxLen + ')]' + CHAR(13) ELSE ' [Required] ' + CHAR(13)  END   
    ELSE
    CASE WHEN Len(MaxLen) > 0 THEN ' [StringLength(' + MaxLen + ')]' + CHAR(13) ELSE '' END  
    END
    + ' public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; } ' + CHAR(13) 
FROM
(
    SELECT  c.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Your code seems to be cut off...

Comment: Yes, for brevity sake. It's quite long. Also the rest of it doesn't matter as much. I just want to check if a column is a primary on line 4-5 and then print out a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the primary keys of all tables in the current database:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(ta.schema_id) SchemaName,
       ta.name TableName,
       SCHEMA_NAME(ta.schema_id) + '.' + ta.name FullName,
       ind.name PrimaryKeyName,
       col.name ColumnName,
       indcol.key_ordinal Ordinal
FROM sys.tables ta
    INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind
        ON ind.object_id = ta.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns indcol
        ON indcol.object_id = ta.object_id
           AND indcol.index_id = ind.index_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns col
        ON col.object_id = ta.object_id
           AND col.column_id = indcol.column_id
WHERE ind.is_primary_key = 1
ORDER BY ta.name,
         indcol.key_ordinal;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I derived this out to select WHERE AND ColumnName = input and then made it into a function and returned a count. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Aquaphor.. no problem. Just one more thing... You probably should choose another approach for your code generation.. it should be far more easier to get the results with e.g. a [powershell script](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/scripting-objects-with-powershell) or [T4 Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/writing-a-t4-text-template?view=vs-2019)... happy coding anyways...